# Changing geometry types from kml points Z to just points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry-conversion

How do I change geometry types from pointZ to point in QGIS from a kmz file?

Answer (score 5):

When loading the kmz file into QGIS, right-click the kmz file and go to 'Save vector layer as', select 'ESRI shapefile' as the target format. In Geometry section, change the Geometry type from Automatic to Point, then uncheck 'Include z-dimension', as you can see below.

[image]

The final output will be a point geometry not pointZ geometry.