# QGIS 2.18.28 Dissolve Error: "-2147483645 See log for more details"

Tags: qgis-2, error, dissolve

I am doing property research on a county in Texas. I have all the parcel data and am trying to dissolve by Owner Name so that I can use the info tool to quickly see all the properties a given person owns in the county. I have dissolved successfully in two other counties already and have employed the same process for this county. But for some reason when I hit "Run" in the dissolve tool, I keep getting the same error message. "-2147483645 See log for more details" See a picture of the error box below.

[image]

Unless I don't know where to look, I am not seeing any information on what the issue is. I have googled the error message with 0 results.

Comment: Have you checked, whether the geometry is faulty or not? Have you tried dissolving using another field?

Comment: When I run the "check validity" tool I get the exact same error message. I have also tried to dissolve by owner address and get the same error message. I even tried to change the layer CRS and still got the same error message.

Comment: If you interpret `-2147483645` as  `HRESULT`, you get `0x80000003`, which means `One or more arguments are invalid`.

Comment: @TomazicM, could you please expend your comment on how you translate the error ? this seem really useful...

Comment: -2147483645 is QGis code for QGis.WKBMultiPolygon25D geometry type (enter that in python console you'll see). Could your shape have Z coordinates that create this issue ?

Comment: My geometry type is "Polygon (WKB type: "PolygonZ")". Should I change that? If so, what should I change it to and how do I change it?

Comment: It's not supposed to be an issue but you could try to drop it with "Convert geometry type" algo to polygon and try again

Comment: Solved! MaxPlank, you were right. The PolygonZ kept the dissolve from working I followed the description here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209250/changing-geometry-types-from-kml-points-z-to-just-points-in-qgis and just changed "points" to "polygon" and then saved as a new shape file. When I tried the dissolve function it now works.